# Create a Mysql trigger on Update, to update another row in the same table

Tags: mysql, triggers, entity-attribute-value

i have a table named tblcustomfieldsvalues where i want to create a trigger for updating a row in the same table, this is the table :
[Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V0XG.png)

The goal is to create conditions like this :

- if the corresponding value = 'some car' where relid=relid and fieldid=11, the updated row will bi id=1
- if the corresponding value = 'another car' where relid=relid and fieldid=11, the updated row will bi id=4   and so on...

I even tried to create a temporary table but i always have the error like ( infinite loop )...

Comment: Not sure why Bill deleted his answer as I think it is spot on: you cannot achieve this via trigger, use multiple updates wrapped into a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another approach, created another table as `log_table` and populate it by insert after updating the first table:

```
BEGIN
  IF NEW.fieldid = 30 THEN
    INSERT INTO log_km (km, voiture)
    SELECT NEW.value, value FROM 
customfieldsvalues WHERE relid = NEW.relid AND fieldid = 11;
  END IF;
END
```

It worked to populate the second table.

Then I created another trigger on the second table to update the first one, I had the error.

How can I do it?
There is the trigger for the second table on insert:

```
BEGIN
UPDATE customfieldsvalues 
SET value = NEW.voiture
WHERE id = 22;
END
```